# Trying to get a random element from an array so that I can mark it as "booked"

Tags: java, arrays, random

This is what I have in my method to randomly select a element in my array, however I'm not sure why it isn't working, I feel like I have tried every way of writing it, any ideas.

```
public static Seat BookSeat(Seat[][] x){

  Seat[][] book = new Seat[12][23];

    if (x != null){  

      book = x[(Math.random()*x.length)];  

    }

  return book;    
}
```

Comment: Your `book` is a `Seat[][]` yet your function has a return type of `Seat`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you explain things makes me think a couple of concepts somehow got crosswired.  I am assuming that book is some (2 dimensional) array of Seat objects from which you want to pick a random one.  In order to do so, you need to specify a random choice for each dimension of the array:

```
// this should be declared elsewhere because if it's local to bookSeat it will be lost
// and reinitialized upon each call to bookSeat
Seat[][] book = new Seat[12][23];

// and this is how, after previous declaration, the function will be called
Seat theBookedSeat = bookSeat(book);

// Okay, now we have selected a random seat, mark it as booked, assuming Seat has a 
// method called book:
theBookedSeat.book();


// and this is the modified function.  Note also that function in Java by convention
// start with a lowercase letter.
public static Seat bookSeat(Seat[][] x){
    if (x != null){  
        // using Random as shown by chm052
        Random r = new Random();
        // need to pick a random one in each dimension
        book = x[r.nextInt(x.length)][r.nextInt(x[0].length)];  
    }
    return book;  
}
```

You should also integrate a test to check whether the selected seat was already booked and repeat the selection:

```
        do {
            // need to pick a random one in each dimension
            book = x[r.nextInt(x.length)][r.nextInt(x[0].length)];
        while (book.isBooked()); // assuming a getter for a boolean indicating
                                 // whether the seat is booked or not
```

But a full-random selection like this has a couple of disadvantages:

1. the selection being random, you can repeatedly fall on already booked seats, and the chances that happens increase with the number of already booked seats.  But even with few booked seats you could be really unlucky and see the loop spin around tens of times before it hits an unbooked seat.
2. you should absolutely test whether there are still unbooked seats left before entering the loop or it will spin indefinitely.

Therefore it might be a good idea to implement a smarter selection routine, eg by randomly picking a row and a seat and start searching from there until the first free seat is encountered, but for first steps this one should do just fine.

I hope this is what you wanted to achieve, if not feel free to comment and allow me to correct and adapt.

Comment: In my main class, I have a 2d array that gets created of type Seat, so I want a method to call that allows me to select a random element from that array and then I can mark that element as 'booked'.

I created the `Seat[][] book` inside the method because I didn't know how to return the value of the method without creating an array inside the method.

Comment: That's exactly the scenario I describe - the `Seat[][] book = new Seat[12][23];` is in your main then, and the call to bookSeat returns 1 Seat object out of the array.  Let me add some more explanation.

Comment: Oh, I think I got it working the method seems to run now, I needed to create a seat object to return the data, and for some reason I thought I had to create an array, I think it is all working now. Thanks a lot for your help. ^^

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I knew I needed to add a tester to it, just wasn't sure how, this should help, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Floor the number returned by the `(Math.random()*x.length)` expression.

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*x.length);
```

At the moment, you're trying to subscript the array with a floating point number.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer will totally work, but here is another way of doing it using [Random.nextInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28%29) if you don't want to have to do all the mathing around:

```
Random r = new Random();
book = x[r.nextInt(x.length)];
```

It uses [java.util.Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html), so make sure you import that if you do this.